# How to get Google Calendar on Windows 8 offline

Tags: windows-8, android, google-calendar

I need a way to sync the calendar from my Android phone to my Windows 8 laptop, preferably using Google Calendar. However, the Win8 calendar app cannot connect to Google Calendar anymore, and there does not seem to be any other apps that can. I need to have offline access to the calendar, so just using it in a browser will not work.

How can I get Google Calendar to sync with a local calendar on Windows 8, and if that's not possible, what would be a good alternative for syncing calendars between an Android and a laptop?

Answer (score 1):

I keep my Google Calendar on a Chrome (browser) tab and access it through a Chrome tile on my Windows 8 Start screen. It syncs properly with my Google calendars my Windows 7 desktop and the ones on my Android phone and tablets.

Comment: Yes, but I need offline access as well and preferably something that I can close and reopen.